# Building WCF service for database operations

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, database, wcf

1. We have a database on some server: database1.mdf located on http://someserver.com.
2. We need to build a WCF service (on C#) with console auto-hosting that will connect to that remote database and provide some functionality like: read records, insert new records, performing 'select' queries, etc..
3. Finally, we need to write client-side page (on JavaScript) that will communicate with that WCF-service and provide information to the client.

I am new in this question and have found a lot of information already, but everything seem to be too complicated with using a lot of different technologies, frameworks, references, etc. I want a very basic but strong solution that can be done with essential MVS tools. So any help on it would be appreciated.

Here what I've done already:

1. The database is accessible from URL: http://someserver.com/database1.mdf where 'someserver' could be localhost for example.
2. I've build a basic WCF service with console auto-hosting. The program looks like:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.ServiceModel;
   using System.ServiceModel.Description;    
   using System.Data.SqlClient;
   using System.Data;

   namespace hostWCF
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               ServiceHost myServiceHost = null;
               try
               {
                   Uri httpBaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4321/myService");

                   myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(myService.myService), httpBaseAddress);
                   myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(myService.ImyService), new WSHttpBinding(), "");            

                   ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                   serviceBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                   myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior);

                   myServiceHost.Open();

                   Console.WriteLine("myService was launched at: {0}", httpBaseAddress);
                   Console.WriteLine();        

                   // DO WE NEED TO MAKE A CONNECTION WITH DATABASE HERE?           

                   Console.ReadKey();                
               }

               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   myServiceHost = null;
                   Console.WriteLine("myService has faced a problem:  " + ex.Message);
                   Console.ReadKey();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

How can I connect to the remote database once the service was launched? Or is it better to make a conection procedure like a service function by putting it into the ImyService [OperationContract]? Maby it is better not to keep the connection al the time, but open it only when client will communicate with the database? Then, how to provide methods that will perform queries to the database? And, finally, how to write a proxy class that will send data in JSON format to the client page?

http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2015/04/create-wcf-data-service.html

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/inserting-data-into-database-using-wcf-service/

I've found thoose two tutorials very helpful (the database approach from the first one and Console Host workout from the second) but I do not want to use ASP.NET Web application (like in the first one). So I wonder how can I add *.svc-based WFC Data Service to the solution like the second one.. It is possible to add service reference to the Host with the code (because service can be found only while the Host is running..), MVS 'Add service reference...' do not see it.

UPDATE:

I moved a little further. Now my WCF console host application looks really simple with local database.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace demoWCFHost
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Name = "binding1";
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:8000/service1");

        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, baseAddress);

        serviceHost.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
        Console.WriteLine(); 
        Console.ReadLine();

        serviceHost.Close();
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string DoWork();
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DoWork() method was called");

            string connectionString = @"data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("database is connected");
                Console.WriteLine();

                string response = String.Empty;

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                response += reader.GetValue(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("database is disconnected");
                Console.WriteLine();

                return response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It handles one method DoWork() that returns all records from the database.
Now I'm trying to call it from JavaScript page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(
            function () {
                $.ajax( {
                  type: 'POST',
                  url:  'http://localhost:8000/service1',
                  data: '<'+'soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                              '<'+'soap:Body>'+
                                '<'+'DoWork xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">'+
                                '<'+'/DoWork>'+
                              '<'+'/soap:Body>'+
                            '<'+'/soap:Envelope>',
                  success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                          $('#results').html(escape(xhr.responseText));
                  },
                  dataType: 'xml'
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it falls with:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/service1           jquery.min.js:140
ajax                                  @ jquery.min.js:140
(anonymous function)                  @ (index):52
ready                                 @ jquery.min.js:28
t                                     @ jquery.min.js:36

(index):1 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/service1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 415.
```

Any ideas on how it can be fixed? Also we still need to make database conection remote instead of local...